# How to acces to a xml content through xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Hi i am trying to transform an xml archive through a xsl archive, what i  want is to create a table showing the content of the xml, but i am not able to show the value of two columns the ones named "complexity" and "subjet", my xml code is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../xsl/showQue``stions.xsl"?>
<assessmentItems>
<assessmentItem complexity="3" subject="mikologia">
    <itemBody> 
        <p>Zein Amanita da jangarria?</p>
    </itemBody>
    <correctResponse>
        <value>Caesarea</value>
    </correctResponse>
    <incorrectResponses>
        <value>Phalloides</value>
        <value>Muscaria</value>
        <value>Virosa</value>
    </incorrectResponses>
</assessmentItem>
<assessmentItem complexity="3" subject="mikologia">
    <itemBody> 
        <p>Tripakiek zer dute kapela azpian?</p>
    </itemBody>
    <correctResponse>
        <value>Eztenak</value>
    </correctResponse>
    <incorrectResponses>
        <value>Filamenduak</value>
        <value>Himenioa</value>
        <value>Hodiak</value>
    </incorrectResponses>
</assessmentItem>
<assessmentItem complexity="5" subject="mikologia">
    <itemBody>
        <p>Eranztuna du</p>
    </itemBody>
    <correctResponse>
        <value>Galanpernak</value>
    </correctResponse>
    <incorrectResponses>
        <value>Gibel urdinak</value>
        <value>Esnegorriak</value>
        <value>Errotariak</value>
    </incorrectResponses>
    </assessmentItem>
</assessmentItems>
```

and this is my xsl:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
        <BODY>
            <h2>Galderak</h2>
            <TABLE border="1">
                <TR>
                    <TH>Testua</TH>
                    <TH>Erantzun zuzena</TH>
                    <TH>Erantzun okerrak</TH>
                    <TH>Zailtasuna</TH>
                    <TH>Arloa</TH>
                </TR>
                <xsl:for-each select="/assessmentItems/assessmentItem" >
                    <TR>
                        <TD><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="red" FACE="Verdana">
                            <xsl:value-of select="itemBody/p"/> <BR/>
                            </FONT>
                        </TD>
                        <TD><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="orange" FACE="Verdana">
                            <xsl:value-of select="correctResponse"/> <BR/>
                            </FONT>
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            <FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="pink" FACE="Verdana">
                            <xsl:value-of select="incorrectResponses/value[1]"/><BR/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="incorrectResponses/value[2]"/> <BR/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="incorrectResponses/value[3]"/> <BR/>
                            </FONT>
                        </TD>
                        <TD><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="green" FACE="Verdana">
                            <xsl:value-of select="complexity"/> <BR/>
                            </FONT>
                        </TD>
                            <TD><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="blue" FACE="Verdana">
                            <xsl:atribute select="subject"/> <BR/>
                            </FONT>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </TABLE>
        </BODY>
    </HTML></xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the table is shown every content except this two colums. Thank you

Comment: Please translate your question into english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the complexity and subject are XML attributes which you need a bit different XPath syntax to reference, for example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="path/to/element/@attribute1" />
```

Note the '@'-sign.

Hence, your specific columns would need to be defined as such:

```
<TD>
    <FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="green" FACE="Verdana">
        <xsl:value-of select="@complexity"/>
        <BR/>
    </FONT>
</TD>
<TD>
    <FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="blue" FACE="Verdana">
        <xsl:value-of select="@subject"/>
        <BR/>
    </FONT>
</TD>
```

Comment: Thanku so much! i thought ive tried that but seems like i didnt so now it works thank youuu!